# Is it possible to remote android phone from a Bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-security

I have a Bluetooth device which can receive a data from the android phone. When it receive a string as 'Request', the device will send a control message to the phone 'Open'. Based on the control message, the android phone can call an Intent service as open a calling. Due to security, I am not sure is it possible in android version 5.0 to 6.0? Can you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible inside your app to handle messages received from other devices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you think my application can run as service?

Comment: Thanks, Do you see any app look like it? Could you suggest to me how can I do it? Because I am worried that the security may be one issue to prevent the control

Comment: You can find many beacon apps which uses these kind of features. I don't think it may generate any security issue .